# Nginx load only few same images. Rest is 404

Tags: file, nginx, load, browser-cache

I set up vps using nginx with multiple nodejs apps. On this apps some of the images aren't loaded. There are always same files. They are all lowercase and have 755 permissions.

Nginx config:

```
server {

        server_name jakubdev.pl www.jakubdev.pl;

        location '/.well-known/acme-challenge' {
        default_type "text/plain";
        root /var/www/portfolio;
   }


        location / {
        proxy_read_timeout      300;
        proxy_connect_timeout   300;
        proxy_redirect          off;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header        Host              $http_host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-Frame-Options   SAMEORIGIN;
        proxy_pass              http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        }
         location /images/ {
        root /var/www/portfolio/public;
        add_header  Cache-control "public";
        access_log  off;
        expires 90d;
        autoindex on;
        autoindex_exact_size off;
}
```

Error log:

```
2019/04/13 16:19:19 [error] 20380#20380: *7 open() "/var/www/portfolio/public/images/icons/iphone/iphone-x.png" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 83.28.244.168, server: jakubdev.pl, request: "GET /$
2019/04/13 16:19:19 [error] 20380#20380: *4 open() "/var/www/portfolio/public/images/icons/iphone/iphone-8.png" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 83.28.244.168, server: jakubdev.pl, request: "GET /$
2019/04/13 16:19:19 [error] 20380#20380: *6 open() "/var/www/portfolio/public/images/icons/iphone/iphone-8-plus.png" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 83.28.244.168, server: jakubdev.pl, request: "$
2019/04/13 16:19:19 [error] 20380#20380: *3 open() "/var/www/portfolio/public/images/icons/iphone/iphone-6s.png" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 83.28.244.168, server: jakubdev.pl, request: "GET $
2019/04/13 16:19:19 [error] 20380#20380: *3 open() "/var/www/portfolio/public/javascripts/parallax.min.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 83.28.244.168, server: jakubdev.pl, request: "GET /javas$
2019/04/13 16:26:11 [warn] 20413#20413: duplicate MIME type "text/css" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:57
2019/04/13 16:26:11 [warn] 20413#20413: duplicate MIME type "application/json" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:57
2019/04/13 16:26:11 [warn] 20413#20413: duplicate MIME type "text/xml" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:57
2019/04/13 16:26:11 [warn] 20413#20413: duplicate MIME type "application/xml" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:57
2019/04/13 16:26:11 [warn] 20413#20413: duplicate MIME type "application/xml+rss" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:57
2019/04/13 16:26:11 [warn] 20413#20413: duplicate MIME type "text/javascript" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:57
2019/04/13 16:26:11 [warn] 20424#20424: duplicate MIME type "text/css" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:57
2019/04/13 16:26:11 [warn] 20424#20424: duplicate MIME type "application/json" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:57
2019/04/13 16:26:11 [warn] 20424#20424: duplicate MIME type "text/xml" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:57
2019/04/13 16:26:11 [warn] 20424#20424: duplicate MIME type "application/xml" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:57
2019/04/13 16:26:11 [warn] 20424#20424: duplicate MIME type "application/xml+rss" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:57
2019/04/13 16:26:11 [warn] 20424#20424: duplicate MIME type "text/javascript" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:57
```

Comment: Do you think this path is correct and this file exists? `/var/www/portfolio/public/images/icons/iphone/iphone-x.png` ?

Comment: Yes ,that's correct path. Strange is that similar named image iphone-xs.png and iphone-7-plus.png works fine that's in same folder. Just this 4 image doesn't work. There's also another folder in public/images that only 2 image's works rest is unreacheable.

Comment: Can it be some fs/disk corruption? Could you check that?

Comment: I know what's wrong, but solution doesn't work. Only lowercase names are loaded. I added to nginx default '~*' before /images/, nothing happend. How Can I make it case insensitive?

Comment: See
https://serverfault.com/questions/935041/how-serve-files-in-folder-with-case-insensitive-on-linux-with-nginx

Think about renaming the files.